# HTML customized select

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I want to create a HTML customized select combo box. What are the libraries available to do that? Or how can do that using CSS?

Example: Gmail sign up style chombo box

Comment: too vague. show us what you tried. your friends: google and jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see this url:

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea that uses jQuery:

```
$('#your-select-id').each(function(){
        var title = $('option:selected', this).text();
        if( $('option:selected', this).val() != ''  ) title = $('option:selected',this).text();
        $(this)
            .css({'z-index':10,'opacity':0,'-khtml-appearance':'none'})
            .after('<span class="select-overlay">' + title + '</span>')
            .change(function(){
                val = $('option:selected',this).text();
                $(this).next().text(val);
            })
        });
```

What this does is puts an stylable overlay in (span "select-overlay") and makes the select box invisible and sitting on top.  When users click on it they get the options from the default select box and it updates the span whenever it changes.

Would be good to show any attempts you've made next time you ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

`<select>` boxes are impossible to style consistently across browsers. You'll need some kind of select-box-replacement script. There are some great ones available for jQuery, such as [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) which applies great styling to all form elements. jQuery UI also has a module for this but it is still in beta at the moment...